# Let rsync take a snapshot of files before copying

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have the following bash script. In the script I use rsync to copy files from a source to a destination. In the first call of rsync I copy all the files and in the second call I double-check the files and if the checksum is valid the copied files are deleted in the source.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
rsync --info=progress2 -r --include='database/session_*.db' --exclude 'database/session*' /local/data/ /import/myNas/data
rsync --info=progress2 -r --include='database/session_*.db' --exclude 'database/session*' --checksum --remove-source-files /local/data/ /import/myNas/data
```

The problem now is that while rsync is running new files are written to `/local/data`. I would like that rsync takes a snapshot of the list of files in source (`/local/data`) when it runs the first time and then only copies these files. In the second run rsync should then also only run on these files from the snapshot (i.e. calculate the checksum and then delete the files). That means the new added files should not be touched.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `find` to put a list of all the files in a temporary file. Then use `--include-from=/tmp/filenames` to copy just those files.

Comment: @Barmar Sounds reasonable. Can you give an example as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: If you are copying the files within a single file system, don't copy the files; just *link* them. Then the new links is by definition identical to the original link, and you don't need to check anything; you can simply let `rsync` delete the source immediately.

Comment: @chepner It is not the same system. The source files are on the local disk of a VM and the destination is on a NAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Populating a `null` delimited list of files to synchronize before running `rsync` with this list:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##### Settings #####

# Location of the source data files
declare -r SRC='/local/data/'

# Destination of the data files
declare -r DEST='/import/myNas/data/'

##### End of Settings #####

set -o errexit # same as set -e, exit if command fail

declare -- _temp_fileslist

trap 'rm -f "$_temp_fileslist"' EXIT

_temp_fileslist=$(mktemp) && typeset -r _temp_fileslist

# Populate files list as null delimited entries
find "$SRC" \
  -path '*/database/session_*.db' \
  -and -not -path '*/database/session*' \
  -fprinf "$_temp_fileslist" '%P\0'

# --from0 tells rsync to read a null delimited list
# --files-from= tells to read the include list from this file
if rsync --info=progress2 --recursive \
  --from0 "--files-from=$_temp_fileslist" -- "$SRC" "$DEST";
then rsync --info=progress2 --recursive \
    --from0 "--files-from=$_temp_fileslist" \
    --checksum --remove-source-files -- "$SRC" "$DEST"
fi
```